# Tried to make 3 moving parts of a screensaver in Processing, got one super fast part. Any ideas?

Tags: processing

I created a screensaver that bounces around the screen. I tried to fit original the code into OOP (which I'm terrible at) so that I could have multiple versions of it bouncing around. Instead, I'm getting one instance travelling at an unusually fast speed.

How can I get `instance1`, `instance2` and `instance3` to be seperate instead of combining into one?

Notes:
In the class `screenSavers`, `C` stands for constructor parameter to differentiate from the original variables at the top. `CS` stands for class-specific to avoid confusion with the original variables at the top. (yes, it's confusing. I don't know why I did that)

*GIANT WALL OF CODE ALERT*

````
import java.lang.Math;

//defining dimensions and initial coords for the laptop frame
float frameW = 120;
float frameH = frameW * 3.0/4.0;
float frameX = random(frameW * 2, width);
float frameY = random(frameW * 2, height);

//defining variables are used in the movement of the laptop
float xSpeed = random(frameW / 50,frameH / 15);
float ySpeed = random(2,5);
boolean moveLeft = false;
boolean moveUp = false;

//defining the colours used in the program, as well as the alpha and stroke widths
int alpha = 255;
color baseColor = color(random(100, 255), random(100, 255), random(100, 255), alpha);
color accentColor = color(random(100, 255), random(100, 255), random(100, 255), alpha);
color baseColorAlpha;
color accentColorAlpha;
color bgColor = 0;
color outline = 255;
int outerCircleWeight = 5;
int laptopStrokeWeight = 1;

//initial states of little ellipses on the screen
float startingPoint = 7.5;
float leftDotRaise = 0;
boolean leftDown = false;
float centerDotRaise = 0;
boolean centerDown = false;
float rightDotRaise = 0;
boolean rightDown = false;

//variable for the radian at which the circles outside the laptop are at
float circleOrbit;

//variable for roundness of any initially circular shapes (ellipses, orbits, etc)
float specialRadii = 200;

//square-ification button
int buttonX = 200;
int buttonY = 200;
boolean buttonState = true;
int buttonTextSize = 30;
String offMessage = "Revert";
String onMessage = "Squarify";
String buttonMessage = onMessage;


public class screenSavers {
  
  float frameWCS;
  float xSpeedCS;
  float ySpeedCS;
  boolean moveLeftCS;
  boolean moveUpCS;
  int alphaCS;
  color baseColorCS;
  color accentColorCS;
  color bgColorCS;
  color outlineCS;
  int outerCircleWeightCS;
  int laptopStrokeWeightCS;
  float startingPointCS;
  float leftDotRaiseCS;
  boolean leftDownCS;
  float centerDotRaiseCS;
  boolean centerDownCS;
  float rightDotRaiseCS;
  boolean rightDownCS;
  float specialRadiiCS;
  int buttonXCS;
  int buttonYCS;
  boolean buttonStateCS;
  int buttonTextSizeCS;
  String offMessageCS;
  String onMessageCS;
  String buttonMessageCS;
  float circleOrbitCS;
  
  public screenSavers (float frameWC, float xSpeedC, float ySpeedC, boolean moveLeftC, boolean moveUpC, int alphaC, color bgColorC, color outlineC, int outerCircleWeightC, int laptopStrokeWeightC, float startingPointC, float leftDotRaiseC, boolean leftDownC, float centerDotRaiseC, boolean centerDownC, float rightDotRaiseC, boolean rightDownC, float specialRadiiC, int buttonXC, int buttonYC, boolean buttonStateC, int buttonTextSizeC, String offMessageC, String onMessageC, String buttonMessageC, float circleOrbitC){
  
    frameWCS = frameWC;
    xSpeedCS = xSpeedC;
    ySpeedCS = ySpeedC;
    moveLeftCS = moveLeftC;
    moveUpCS = moveUpC;
    alphaCS = alphaC;
    bgColorCS = bgColorC;
    outlineCS = outlineC;
    outerCircleWeightCS = outerCircleWeightC;
    laptopStrokeWeightCS = laptopStrokeWeightC;
    startingPointCS = startingPointC;
    leftDotRaiseCS = leftDotRaiseC;
    leftDownCS = leftDownC;
    centerDotRaiseCS = centerDotRaiseC;
    centerDownCS = centerDownC;
    rightDotRaiseCS = rightDotRaiseC;
    rightDownCS = rightDownC;
    specialRadiiCS = specialRadiiC;
    buttonXCS = buttonXC;
    buttonYCS = buttonYC;
    buttonStateCS = buttonStateC;
    buttonTextSizeCS = buttonTextSizeC;
    offMessageCS = offMessageC;
    onMessageCS = onMessageC;
    buttonMessageCS = buttonMessageC;
    circleOrbitCS = circleOrbitC;
    
  }
  
    public void main(String[] args){
    
    
    }
  
    public void updateAlpha(){
  
      /*
      updates alpha versions of color variables that account for the alpha of the color, we have to put this
      so that it updates every frame, otherwise the transparency will only update with every bounce. This way
      the color updates with each bounce but the transparency constantly updates every frame (or 60 times per second)
      */
      baseColorAlpha = color(red(baseColor),green(baseColor),blue(baseColor), alpha);
      accentColorAlpha = color(red(accentColor),green(accentColor),blue(accentColor), alpha);
      
      /*
      transparency of objects changes with X position of the mouse, 1st quarter of the screen
       = 25% brightness, 2nd quarter =  50%, 3rd quarter = 75%, 4th quarter = 100%
      */
      
      if (mouseX < width / 3){
      alpha = 75;
      } else 
      if (mouseX > width / 3 && mouseX < 2 * width / 3) {
      alpha = 150;
      } else
      if (mouseX > width * 2 / 3 && mouseX < width){
      alpha = 255;
      }
    
    }
  
    void resetBackground(){
    
      //reset background to prevent copies of the laptop from generating
      background(bgColor);
      //set outline color
      stroke(outline);
      fill(baseColorAlpha);
  
    }
  
    void updateRadii (){
      
      //changing radii of shapes based on button
      if (buttonStateCS == true){
      
        specialRadiiCS = 2 * frameW;
      
      } else {
      
        specialRadiiCS = 0;
      
      }
      
    }
    
    
    void generateComputer(){
      
      //making the frame
      rect(frameX, frameY, frameW, frameH);
    
      //making the screen
      fill(accentColorAlpha);
      rect(frameX, frameY, frameW - frameW / 5, frameH - frameH * 4.0/15.0);
      
      //switching back to the base color for the moving ellipses on the screen
      fill(baseColorAlpha);
      
      //creating the laptop keyboard
      fill(accentColorAlpha);
      beginShape(); 
      vertex(frameX - frameW / 2, frameY + frameH / 2);
      vertex(frameX - (frameW / 2 + 15), frameY + frameH / 2 + 15);
      vertex(frameX + frameW / 2 + 15, frameY + frameH / 2 + 15);
      vertex(frameX + frameW / 2, frameY + frameH / 2);
      endShape();
      
    }
    
    void dots(){
      
      rect(frameX - frameW / 5,frameY + leftDotRaise + startingPoint,frameH / 5,frameH / 5,specialRadiiCS);
      
      //moving the dots
      if (leftDotRaise >= frameH * (11.0 / 75.0)){
        leftDown = false;
      } else
      if (leftDotRaise <= frameH * (-11.0 / 75.0)){
        leftDown = true;
      }
      
      if (leftDown == true){
        leftDotRaise += frameH / 75;
      } else if (leftDown == false){
        leftDotRaise -= frameH / 75;
      }
      
      
      rect(frameX,frameY + centerDotRaise, frameH / 5, frameH / 5,specialRadiiCS);
      
      if (centerDotRaise >= frameH * (11.0 / 75.0)){
        centerDown = false;
      } else
      if (centerDotRaise <= frameH * (-11.0 / 75.0)){
        centerDown = true;
      }
      
      if (centerDown == true){
        centerDotRaise += frameH / 75;
      } else if (centerDown == false){
        centerDotRaise -= frameH / 75;
      }
      
      
      
      rect(frameX + frameW / 5,frameY + rightDotRaise - startingPoint,frameH / 5,frameH / 5,specialRadiiCS);
      
      if (rightDotRaise >= frameH * (11.0 / 75.0)){
        rightDown = false;
      } else
      if (rightDotRaise <= frameH * (-11.0 / 75.0)){
        rightDown = true;
      }
      
      if (rightDown == true){
        rightDotRaise += frameH / 75;
      } else if (rightDown == false){
        rightDotRaise -= frameH / 75;
      }
      
      startingPoint = 0;
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    void generateOrbitals(){
      
      //creating and animated the outer rotating circles
      pushMatrix();
      translate(frameX, frameY);
      rotate(circleOrbitCS);
      translate(frameW * 1.5, frameH / -10);
      circleOrbitCS += 0.01;
      rect(0, 0, frameW / 2, frameW / 2, specialRadiiCS);
      popMatrix();
    
      pushMatrix();
      translate(frameX, frameY);
      rotate(circleOrbitCS);
      translate(frameW * -1.5, frameH / 10);
      circleOrbitCS += 0.01;
      rect(0, 0, frameW / 2, frameW / 2, specialRadiiCS);
      popMatrix();
    
      pushMatrix();
      translate(frameX, frameY);
      rotate(circleOrbitCS);
      translate(frameH / 10, frameW * 1.5);
      circleOrbit += 0.01;
      rect(0, 0, frameW / 2, frameW / 2, specialRadiiCS);
      popMatrix();
    
      pushMatrix();
      translate(frameX, frameY);
      rotate(circleOrbit);
      translate(frameH / -10, frameW * -1.5);
      circleOrbit += 0.01;
      rect(0, 0, frameW / 2,frameW / 2, specialRadiiCS);
      popMatrix();
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    void generateOuterCircle(){
      
       noFill();
      stroke(accentColor);
      strokeWeight(outerCircleWeight);
      rect(frameX, frameY, frameW * 4, frameW * 4,specialRadii);
      strokeWeight(laptopStrokeWeight);
    
    }
    
    void bounce(){
    
      if (frameX + 2 * frameW > width) {
    
        moveLeft = true;
        baseColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
        accentColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
    
      } else if (frameX - 2 * frameW < 0) {
    
        moveLeft = false;
        baseColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
        accentColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
    
      }
    
      if (frameY + 8.0/3.0 * frameH > height) {
    
        moveUp = true;
        baseColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
        accentColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
    
      } else if (frameY - 8.0/3.0 * frameH < 0) {
    
        moveUp = false;
        baseColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
        accentColor = color(random(50, 255), random(50, 255), random(50, 255),alpha);
    
      }
    
      if (moveLeft == true) {
    
        xSpeed = abs(xSpeed) * -1;
    
      } else {
    
        xSpeed = abs(xSpeed);
    
      }
    
      if (moveUp == true) {
    
        ySpeed = abs(ySpeed) * -1;
    
      } else {
    
        ySpeed = abs(ySpeed);
    
    
      }
    
    }
    
    void updateCoords(){
      
        //update coords  
      println("Screensaver Icon is currently at (" + frameX + ", " + frameY + ')');
    
    }
    
    void generateSquareButton(){
    
      //square-ification button
      
      
      fill(accentColor);
      rect(buttonXCS,buttonYCS, 200, 200, specialRadiiCS);
      fill(255);
      textSize(buttonTextSizeCS);
      text(buttonMessageCS,buttonXCS,buttonYCS+5);
    
    }
    
    void alignShapes(){
    
      //letting the program know that we are referencing X and Y coords of a rectangle or text box by its center
        rectMode(CENTER);
        textAlign(CENTER);
    
    }
    
    void testForButton(){
    
    //check if the mouse was pressed at the button's coordinates
      if (mouseX > buttonXCS - 100  && mouseY > buttonYCS - 100 && mouseX < buttonXCS + 50 && mouseY < buttonYCS + 50){
      
        //if the button is on, turn it off
        if (buttonStateCS == true){
        
          buttonStateCS = false;
          buttonMessageCS = offMessageCS;
        
        } else
        //if the button is off, turn it on
        if (buttonStateCS == false){
        
          buttonStateCS = true;
          buttonMessageCS = onMessageCS;
        
        }
      
      }
    
    }
    
    void move(){
    
      frameX += xSpeed;
      frameY += ySpeed;
    
    }
    
    void display(){
    
      updateAlpha();
      resetBackground();
      updateRadii();
      generateComputer();
      dots();
      generateOrbitals();
      generateOuterCircle();
      bounce();
      move();
      updateCoords();
      generateSquareButton();
    
    }
  
  
    
  }
  
  
  
  //creating the first instance of the screensaver as an object
  screenSavers instance1 = new screenSavers(frameW,xSpeed,ySpeed,moveLeft,moveUp,alpha,bgColor,outline,outerCircleWeight,laptopStrokeWeight,startingPoint,leftDotRaise,leftDown,centerDotRaise, centerDown, rightDotRaise, rightDown, specialRadii, buttonX, buttonY, buttonState, buttonTextSize, offMessage, onMessage, buttonMessage,circleOrbit);
  //creating the second instance of the screensaver as an object
  screenSavers instance2 = new screenSavers(frameW,xSpeed,ySpeed,moveLeft,moveUp,alpha,bgColor,outline,outerCircleWeight,laptopStrokeWeight,startingPoint,leftDotRaise,leftDown,centerDotRaise, centerDown, rightDotRaise, rightDown, specialRadii, buttonX, buttonY, buttonState, buttonTextSize, offMessage, onMessage, buttonMessage,circleOrbit);
  //creating the third instance of the screensaver as an object
  screenSavers instance3 = new screenSavers(frameW,xSpeed,ySpeed,moveLeft,moveUp,alpha,bgColor,outline,outerCircleWeight,laptopStrokeWeight,startingPoint,leftDotRaise,leftDown,centerDotRaise, centerDown, rightDotRaise, rightDown, specialRadii, buttonX, buttonY, buttonState, buttonTextSize, offMessage, onMessage, buttonMessage,circleOrbit);



//setup loop, runs ONCE
void setup() {

  /*note: to see the console update the X and Y, comment out fullScreen();  
  and un-comment size(1000,1000); */  
    
  //enters fullscreen, regardless of device resolution  
  fullScreen();  
    
  //uncomment this for seeing coords updated  
  //size(1000,1000);  
    
  
  //makes the framerate go from 24 to a smoother 60 frames. If I don't add this your eyes will hurt
  frameRate(60);
  
  
  
  
  

  
  instance1.alignShapes();
  instance2.alignShapes();
  instance3.alignShapes();


  
}

void draw() {
  

  instance1.display();
  instance2.display();
  instance3.display();


 
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//do something when mouse is pressed
void mousePressed(){
  
  instance1.testForButton();
  instance2.testForButton();
  instance3.testForButton();


  
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it a few days later by the way, I was looking for the `this` keyword

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Right now you initialize all 3 instances with the exact same properties. They are only "combined" because you made them the same. You should identify what you want to be different between them, and pass in different properties.

Other notes:

- Why does screenSavers have a main() function? Delete it
- Please rename it to ScreenSaver.
- Do not distinguish using C vs CS. Just name them the same. But use the `this` keyword to distinguish the class vars. example: `this.frameW = frameW;`
- Use proper indentation with if statements.

Comment: Quick question then, are the variables initialized in the constructor method are shared by all objects or is there a different version of those variables for each object?

Comment: No, they are different between each object. This is because they are all "primitive" types (ints, floats, booleans, and strings). If you still wanted a value to be shared, you would have to make it "static".

Comment: In fact, you can initialize the values within the class itself, rather than passing them in when creating the object, and they would still be distinct. (this saves a lot of space)

Comment: I forgot to mention something; edited my comment to make it correct